# 3+1 foliations of a spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology

I would like to know can any Lorentzian manifold be 3+1 foliated? I would like to know when a 3+1 [foliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation) of a Lorentzian manifold exists and when it does not exist. If a 3+1 foliation does not exist, can it have other kinds of foliations?

Comment: Not all Lorentzian four-dimensional spacetimes can be foliated by 3-manifolds in a "space and time splitting" way. The result you seem to be looking for is that *globally hyperbolic spacetimes* admit such foliation. These are spacetimes containing a Cauchy surface, which is a hypersurface such that every inextendible causal curve pierces exactly once. If $\Sigma$ is such a surface, the result is that the spacetime is topologically $\mathbb{R}\times \Sigma$ and can be foliated by copies of said Cauchy surface. See Wald's GR book for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233516/2451

Comment: See also links here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/761289/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/696289/226902